# can I use 2 foreach loops in 1 statement in powershell?

Tags: windows, loops, powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0

well I am pretty much trying to include two "get content files" and loop them into a get service cmdlet. Problem is it seems that I can only use one foreach loops to pass on 2 different contents in the get-service cmdlet

```
$ask1 = Read-Host -Prompt "1 for single server, 2 for multiple"


if ($ask1 -eq 1) {

$service = Read-Host -Prompt "enter process"
$server = Read-Host -Prompt "enter server name"

Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server

} else {

$invoke1 = Invoke-Item "u:\Scripts\Servers.txt" 
$invoke2 = Invoke-Item "u:\Scripts\Process.txt"

$ask2 = Read-Host -Prompt "press 1 to continue" 

   while ($ask1 -eq 2) {

      if ($ask2 -eq 1) {
      $content1 = Get-Content "U:\Scripts\process.txt"
      $content2 = Get-Content "U:\Scripts\servers.txt"

      Write-Host "servers are " $content2
      Write-Host "process looking for are " $content1

  foreach ($item in $content1) -and ($item2 in $content2) {     
     Get-Service -name $item -ComputerName $item2  | Format-List -Property MachineName,status,Displayname 

  }


      }
      break
   }


}
```

if you see this part

foreach ($item in $content1) -and ($item2 in $content2) {
     Get-Service -name $item -ComputerName $item2  | Format-List -Property MachineName,status,Displayname

}

you will see I am trying to get the contents of 2 different places. one for servers and one for services. Is there anyways to include a 2nd forea loop?

Comment: `Get-Service -Name $content1 -ComputerName $content2`

Answer (score 3):

If the the two files have the same number of lines, you can use a classic for loop instead:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $content1.Count; $i++)
{
    Get-Service -Name $content1[$i] -ComputerName $content2[$i]
}
```

---

If you are trying to retrieve all services listed in `$content1` on every single computer listed in `$content2`, use a nested loop:

```
foreach($serviceName in $content1)
{
    foreach($computerName in $content2)
    {
        Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ComputerName $computerName
    }
}
```